# How to return an object outside of mongoose .save().then()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, promise, graphql

I have a GraphQL mutation that attempts to save an object to a MongoDB collection using Mongoose:

```
Mutation: {
    addPost: (parent, args) => {
      let output = {};
      const newpost = new dbPost({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        title: args.title,
        content: args.content,
        author: {
          id: args.authorid,
          first_name: args.authorfirstname,
          last_name: args.authorlastname,
        }
      });
      newpost.save().then((result) => {
        output = result;
      });
      return output // returns null, need result!
    },
  }
```

The script works just fine as in it successfully saves the object (passed to it through *args*) to the collection. However, I'm unable to return the object returned from inside *.then()* for further processing. In GraphiQL, the response is a null object. Is there any way, I could return the value of **result** outside of **.then()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use async await like this:

```
  Mutation: {
      addPost: async (parent, args) => {
        let output = {};
        const newpost = new dbPost({
          _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
          title: args.title,
          content: args.content,
          author: {
            id: args.authorid,
            first_name: args.authorfirstname,
            last_name: args.authorlastname,
          }
        });
        output = await newpost.save();
        return output 
      },
    }
```

then from where you call addPost call it like: await Mutation.addPost

Answer (score 0):

[@Mehranaz.sa answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52357985/2586595) is correct!

But GraphQL resolves Promise so you could simply write this:

```
Mutation: {
    addPost: (parent, args) => {
      let output = {};
      const newpost = new dbPost({
        title: args.title,
        content: args.content,
        author: {
          id: args.authorid,
          first_name: args.authorfirstname,
          last_name: args.authorlastname,
        }
      });
      return newpost.save();
    },
  }
```

It works fine too!
PS: You don't need to provide _id when you're using ObjectId:)